# Function to check the time and run program according to that time.

Tags: php, function, time

I am writing the function for Estimate a time. i-e run a specific event according to time... Suppose I have an Array of times

```
$times = array(
    '00:00' => 'Programme 1',
    '00:30' => 'Programme 2',
    '01:00' => 'Programme 3',
    '01:30' => 'Programme 4',
    '02:00' => 'Programme 5',
    '02:30' => 'Programme 6',
    '03:00' => 'Programme 7',
    '03:30' => 'Programme 8',
    '04:00' => 'Programme 9',
    '04:30' => 'Programme 10',
    '05:00' => 'Programme 10',
);
```

And function

```
echo (currently_should_play("00:05", $times) === 'Programme 1' ? 'Ok 1' : 'Not Ok 1') . PHP_EOL;
```

It should match if first time is less than second time its should run the first and if its equal to exact value than its run that even...

The upper function call should Matched with 00:00 and print 'ok'

Let's suppose another example

```
echo (currently_should_play("00:58", $time) === 'Programme 2' ? 'Ok 2' : 'Not Ok 2') . PHP_EOL;
```

its should match with second value because its match with Programme 2...

Please advice some solution..

My function code is here in which i get the key and value from array

```
function currently_should_play($current_time, array $times) {
   foreach ($times as $time => $programme) {
    echo $time;
    echo $programme."<br/>";

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function currently_should_play($current_time, array $times) {
  $s=size($times);
  while($s-->0){
   if($times[$s]==$current_time){
    return $times[$s];
   }elseif($times[$s-1]==$current_time){
    return $times[$s-1];
   }elseif($times[$s-1]<$current_time&&$times[$s]>$current_time){
    return $times[$s-1];
   }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Its says size is not defined when i change it to sizeof its show offset error.... did you try on your end?